# Shortcut for reload jscript file

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

I am using `notepad++ for jscript` file editing and `TestComplete` for automation testing which uses the JScript files, but every time i exit and start the TestComplete whenever i change anything in Jscript file.

is there any `short-cut-Key` to reload without closing the `TestComplete`.

Comment: Could you please clarify how exactly you run TestComplete and how you use JScript file you created in Notepad++? Does the file contain test scripts executed by TestComplete or code that starts and closes TestComplete?

Comment: @DmitryN : TestComplete loads all the Jscript file when it starts, while i edit & update the Jscript file using Notepad++ anytime after started the TestComplete. Then it is required to refresh/reload somehow the Jscript file into TestComplete. this is what i want to do by any short-cut-key. but for time being i just restart the testComeplet so it loads the files whatsoever i have edited in notepad.

Comment: for example : Files location - `C:\Jscript\files\*` TestComplete loads all file from this location when starts. I can edit any file using `NotePad++` from this location.

Comment: Actually, TestComplete reloads all script units added to the current project when test execution is started. I have just checked this with TestComplete 9.10. Which version of TestComplete you have?

Comment: Also, are your script files added to a TestComplete project as script units? If not, how exactly are these scripts read by TestComplete?

Comment: @DmitryN: thanks for your time.Version is TestComplete 9.0.1312.7. My colleague told me to use `ALT+F+E -> A window popUp -> click on Reload and thenk Click OK`.   
Whether i am not very sure how it works by using this shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are creating a script extension. Thank you for clarification. I have checked the **Tools | Customize Keyboard...** dialog and there is no a possibility to assign a shortcut to the **Reload Script Extensions** action. So, you can do this only by manually clicking the **Reload** button in the **Script Extensions** dialog. The **Alt-F-E** shortcut just opens this dialog (**File | Install Script Extensions...**).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.philnicholas.com/2009/05/11/reloading-your-javascript-without-reloading-your-page/

This page explains what you're looking for, I think. All you need to do is change the event to when ur shortcut key is pressed.

Comment: maybe you could create a little plug in, that will refresh the source when you presh the short cut key.